# OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. Source parameters not found to download the source file

Tags: opshub

I have a problem with the OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility. It sometimes halts at a apparently randome changeset during migration, and I am not able to get it to continue. The error message of the failed changeset is:

> OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. Source parameters not found to
>   download the source
>   file:24::3117::$/Solution/Project/ProjectFolder/SomeFile.cs

I have succeded with migration of a couple of project by repeating the whole thing. But for larger projects I never get through the complete migration. And the problematic changeset is different each time. 
Looking at the log, i could find some exceptions thrown like this:

```
08/11/2016 12:10:30,922 ERROR [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] (org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement) - action threw exception: script evaluation exception
org.jbpm.graph.def.DelegationException: script evaluation exception
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:139)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:73)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.execute(Script.java:62)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.executeAction(GraphElement.java:259)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.executeActions(GraphElement.java:215)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.fireAndPropagateEvent(GraphElement.java:185)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.fireEvent(GraphElement.java:169)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Transition.take(Transition.java:138)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Node.leave(Node.java:393)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:192)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:140)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.ProcessInstance.signal(ProcessInstance.java:270)
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeTask(ProcessEngine.java:190)
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeProcess(ProcessEngine.java:60)
    at com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess.syncEvent(SyncEaiProcess.java:230)
    at com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess.sync(SyncEaiProcess.java:137)
    at com.opshub.eai.OIMEventGenerator.process(OIMEventGenerator.java:428)
    at com.opshub.jobs.core.OHJob.execute(OHJob.java:125)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: com.opshub.eai.core.exceptions.OIMSCMAdapterException: OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. Source parameters not found to download the source file:24::3117::$/Solution/Project/ApiControllers/PersonServiceController.cs
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.sync(OIMSCMAdapter.java:409)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHVariableDeclarator.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHTypedVariableDeclaration.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:130)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Source parameters not found to download the source file:24::3117::$/Solution/Project/ApiControllers/PersonServiceController.cs
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSVersionControlConnector.checkInAll(TFSVersionControlConnector.java:166)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSSourceAdapter.checkIn(TFSSourceAdapter.java:246)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSSourceAdapter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2a6a7d04.CGLIB$checkIn$17(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSSourceAdapter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2a6a7d04$$FastClassByCGLIB$$cee96b8e.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.caching.AdapterCacheHandler.intercept(AdapterCacheHandler.java:185)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSSourceAdapter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2a6a7d04.checkIn(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.sync(OIMSCMAdapter.java:325)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: Source parameters not found to download the source file:24::3117::$/Solution/Project/ApiControllers/PersonServiceController.cs
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.opshub.tfs.test.BasicHttpBinding_ITFSWebServiceStub.checkinAllStatus(BasicHttpBinding_ITFSWebServiceStub.java:6282)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSVersionControlConnector.checkInAll(TFSVersionControlConnector.java:155)
    ... 41 more
08/11/2016 12:10:30,924 ERROR [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] (com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess) - Error in executing process definition : SCM Default Integration Workflow at node callMethodOpsHub-012013: Process execution failed on node: callMethod, in process definition: 'SCM Default Integration Workflow'; nested exception is : script evaluation exception 
com.opshub.exceptions.eai.EAIProcessEngineException: OpsHub-012013: Process execution failed on node: callMethod, in process definition: 'SCM Default Integration Workflow'; nested exception is : script evaluation exception
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeTask(ProcessEngine.java:212)
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeProcess(ProcessEngine.java:60)
    at com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess.syncEvent(SyncEaiProcess.java:230)
    at com.opshub.eai.SyncEaiProcess.sync(SyncEaiProcess.java:137)
    at com.opshub.eai.OIMEventGenerator.process(OIMEventGenerator.java:428)
    at com.opshub.jobs.core.OHJob.execute(OHJob.java:125)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: org.jbpm.graph.def.DelegationException: script evaluation exception
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:139)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:73)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.execute(Script.java:62)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.executeAction(GraphElement.java:259)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.executeActions(GraphElement.java:215)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.fireAndPropagateEvent(GraphElement.java:185)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.GraphElement.fireEvent(GraphElement.java:169)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Transition.take(Transition.java:138)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Node.leave(Node.java:393)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:192)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:140)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.ProcessInstance.signal(ProcessInstance.java:270)
    at com.opshub.eai.ProcessEngine.executeTask(ProcessEngine.java:190)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.opshub.eai.core.exceptions.OIMSCMAdapterException: OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. Source parameters not found to download the source file:24::3117::$/Solution/Project/ApiControllers/PersonServiceController.cs
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.sync(OIMSCMAdapter.java:409)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHVariableDeclarator.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHTypedVariableDeclaration.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.jbpm.graph.action.Script.eval(Script.java:130)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Source parameters not found to download the source file:24::3117::$/Solution/Project/ApiControllers/PersonServiceController.cs
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSVersionControlConnector.checkInAll(TFSVersionControlConnector.java:166)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSSourceAdapter.checkIn(TFSSourceAdapter.java:246)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSSourceAdapter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2a6a7d04.CGLIB$checkIn$17(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSSourceAdapter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2a6a7d04$$FastClassByCGLIB$$cee96b8e.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.caching.AdapterCacheHandler.intercept(AdapterCacheHandler.java:185)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSSourceAdapter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2a6a7d04.checkIn(<generated>)
    at com.opshub.eai.core.adapters.OIMSCMAdapter.sync(OIMSCMAdapter.java:325)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: Source parameters not found to download the source file:24::3117::$/Solution/Project/ApiControllers/PersonServiceController.cs
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.opshub.tfs.test.BasicHttpBinding_ITFSWebServiceStub.checkinAllStatus(BasicHttpBinding_ITFSWebServiceStub.java:6282)
    at com.opshub.eai.tfssource.adapter.TFSVersionControlConnector.checkInAll(TFSVersionControlConnector.java:155)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Hi, can you confirm the version of the utility installed? This was a defect in an older version of the tool, was fixed some time ago. Please download the latest version of OVSMU. (Please note that the newer version of the utility has introduced some limitations in the Free Version. Please read the limitations and Free vs Premium section before updating) (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2)

Comment: @OpshubInc. Hi, the version I was using was the 2.2.4 version. I got it in June so I thought it  was the newest. But I have installed version 2.2.5.003 now, and it worked on first try. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the newest version solved my problem. The failing version was 2.2.4 and the new version is 2.2.5.